# Making a quiz: stuck on adding additional answers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a quiz and I'm stuck. I want to add other possible answers to the `<li>` by adding them from an array inside my state object on top (`state.possibleAnswers`). I added a random number generator to the code on line 67, but I guess there must be something wrong on that line since the answers don't show on the DOM. Can anyone have a look at my code and see what causes the error?

```js
var state = {
 questions: [
 {number: 1, question:"What is the capital of Perú?", answer: "Lima", display:true}, {number: 2, question:"What is the capital of Ecuador?", answer: "Quito", display:false}, {number: 3, question:"What is the capital of Colombia", answer: "Bogotá", display:false},
 {number: 4, question:"What is the capital of Paraguay?", answer: "Ascuncion", display:false}, {number: 5, question:"What is the capital of Argentina?", answer: "Buenos Aires", display:false}, {number: 6, question:"What is the capital of Chile?", answer: "Santiago", display:false},
 {number: 7, question:"What is the capital of Brazil?", answer: "Brasilia", display:false}, {number: 8, question:"What is the capital of Bolivia?", answer: "La paz", display:false}, {number: 9, question:"What is the capital of Venezuela?", answer: "Caracas", display:false},
 {number: 10, question:"What is the capital of Uruguay", answer: "Lima", display:false}
 ],
 correctAnswers: 0,
 possibleAnswers: ['Lima', 'Montevideo', 'Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia', 'Bogota', 'Caracas', 'Quito', 'San José', 'Paramaribo', 'La paz']
};


var template = (
 '<li class="js-quiz-card">' +
  '<h6 class="js-question-number"></h6>' +
  '<h6 class="js-questions-correct"></h6>' +
 
  '<div class="js-card-main-section">' +
   '<h3 class="js-question"></h3>' +
   '<ul class="js-possible-answers">' +
   '<li class="js-answer-1"></li>' +
   '<li class="js-answer-2"></li>' +
   '<li class="js-answer-3"></li>' +
   '<li class="js-answer-4"></li>' +
  '</div>' +
  '<button class="js-next-question-button"> Next question </button>' +
 '</li>'
);

function generateRandomNumber(number) {
 Math.floor(Math.random() * number);
}


// STATE MANAGEMENT

function updateScore (state, index) {
 var selectedChoice = $('.selected').text();
 if (selectedChoice === state.questions[index].answer) {
  state.correctAnswers ++;
 }
}

function changeDisplay (state, index) {
 var currentIndexDisplay = state.questions[index].display;
 state.questions[index].display = !currentIndex;
 var newIndexDisplay = state.questions[index + 1 ].display;
 state.questions[index + 1].display = !newIndex;
}


// DOM MANIPULATION

function renderCard (item, itemId, template, itemDataAttr) {
 var element = $(template);
 if (item.display === false) {
  element.addClass("cards-display");
 }
 
 element.find('.js-question-number').text("Question " + item.number + "of 10");
 element.find('.js-questions-correct').text(state.correctAnswers + " questions correct");
 element.find('.js-question').text(item.question);
 var listItems = element.find('.js-possible-answers').children();
 listItems.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)).text(item.answer);
 for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  if (listItems.eq(i).text() === "") {
   listItems.eq(i).text(state.possibleAnswers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)]) ;
  }
 }
 element.attr(itemDataAttr, itemId);
 
 return element;
}




function renderList(state, listElement, itemDataAttr) {
 var htmlString = state.questions.map(
  function(item, index){
   return renderCard(item, index, template, itemDataAttr);
  });
 listElement.html(htmlString);
} 


// EVENT LISTENERS

// click the button and add all the li's to the DOM

function startQuiz(state, listElement, itemDataAttr) {
$('.start-quiz-button').click(function(event){
renderList(state, listElement, itemDataAttr);
});
}



function selectAnswer () {
 $('.js-possible-answers').on('click', 'li', function(event){
  event.currentTarget.addClass('selected');
 });
}

function clickNextButton (listElement, itemDataAttr, state) {
$('.js-next-question-button').click(function(event){
 var index = event.currentTarget.parent('.js-quiz-card').attr(itemDataAttr);
 updateScore(state, index);
 $('js-possible-answers').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
 changeDisplay(state, index);
 renderList(state,listElement, itemDataAttr);
});
}



$(function() {
  
   // html ul on which we will add all the different question cards
  var listElement = $('.question-cards');
 // we'll use this attribute to store the id of the list item
  var itemDataAttr = 'data-list-item-id';

 


  startQuiz(state, listElement, itemDataAttr);

  selectAnswer();

  clickNextButton();

});
```

```css
.question-cards{
 border: 2px solid black;
 padding: 20px;
}

.question-card{
 border: 2px solid grey;
 padding: 10px; 
}


.cards-display {
display: none;
}



.selected {
 background-color:  #27E7E1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Quiz night tonight</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Quiz night tonight</h1>
<h3>Try to answer 7 questions correctly</h3>
<button class="start-quiz-button">try me</button>

<ul class ='question-cards'> 
 
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `=== false` looks very strange.  You are comparing a string to a boolean and not allowing for variable type coersion, which should always result in it being false.  EDIT: as far as properly showing code on here, hit Ctrl+M while in the editor to bring up the onsite code editor.

Comment: Ok, do you have a suggestion to what I could change it so that the possible answers are added?

Thanks for the post tip too.

Comment: I don't have any context into what the value of the list items actually are.  Take my note about the Ctrl+M and update your question to include the logic associated with your question.

Comment: I changed the 'false' to ''" and now it shows the answers as well.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Hey man, sorry to bother you again. Could you have a look at why I can't use the function selectAnswer() ? I try clicking the list items but they don;t respond...

Comment: Are you ever re-creating the '.js-possible-answers' after you have performed the binding on them?  New version of those elements would no longer have the bindings set on them.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your button does not have a click event handler on it. So when you click it, it does nothing. In Chrome you can view this by inspecting the button & clicking the Event Listeners tab. It should be showing a click event handler but it is not. You are calling your clickNextButton function before the user has clicked the "try me" button which creates your next question button in your HTML so the click handler never gets added.

It also appears you have a clickNextButton being called on line 176 without any parameters but the function you wrote on line 150 requires 3 parameters.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm still figuring out how post code. I added the event listener part now. I still have some issues with the event handler, but I got the list to appear all answers now so it's a start :)

Comment: I used to ctrl + m to post like the guy above you suggested and it looks better now.